# Setting Focusable On RadTreeViewItem does not Follow the Default Foucable Behaviour

Tags: wpf, telerik, radtreeview

In the Telerik Radtreeview I want some of the treeviewitems to be unSelectable until the previous steps are completed. In the background I have a Boolean property isSelectable which is Binded to the TreeviewItem Focusable Property. Before when I was using the windows TreeView Control this Focusable property made the treeviewitems to be UnSelected until the previous steps were completed which is a default behaviour in windows control. Now after converting to the telerik Radtreeview control I can select items even with focusable property set to false And also the treeviewitem are highlighted on hovering over the item. Is there a way I can make it to work so that on setting the RadTreeviewItem focusable property to false the respective Radtreeviewitems are not selectable and shouldn’t highlight on mouse over as a default Focus Behaviour?  following snippet is an example to demonstrate the issue with the focusable property where even with focusable false category1 can be selected and highlighted.

Thanks.

```
<telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="radTreeView">
      <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Category1" Focusable="False">  
         <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Product1" Focusable="True" />  
         <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Product2" /> 
         <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Product3" />  
      </telerik:RadTreeViewItem>                    
      <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Category2" Focusable="False" />  
      <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Category3" />
      <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Category4" Focusable="False"> 
          <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Product A" Focusable="True" />  
          <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Product B" /> 
          <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Product C" /> 
      </telerik:RadTreeViewItem> 
      <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Category5" />  
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```